# Write HTML tags Inside <script>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, compiler-construction, editor

I am making a React Online compiler. I know that using HTML and JavaScript could possibly build a online react compiler, as React provides a online CDN!

But, I am new to react. Well, the output from the code will be rendered somelike below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body> ${htmlCode}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script>${ jsCode }</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here, JavaScript will replace the ${htmlCode} with the value of the variable `htmlCode`. Same, ${jsCode} will replace the provided ReactJS code. Above the  tag, you can see the CDN that I am loading to the page.

Now on, if the html code is the below:

```
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

and...below JavaScript code:

```
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return e(
      'button',
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      'Like'
    );
  }
}
```

When the ${jsCode} will be replaced with the JavaScript code, the special symbols included in the Script inherits the HTML. < and > mostly interhit the HTML.

This is the problem!
I created a new JS file and then loaded it in the HTML. But, as in the compiler, the compiler can't create a new file for the JavaScript. So, how can I stop the ReactJS code inheriting the HTML Code?

I also tried to create blob URLS, blob URLS are created but the blob URL is not able to be loaded into the HTML page.

Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

Do you render the `LikeButton` component to the main DOM? React needs to render virtual DOM.

You could see more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#step-3-create-a-react-component